# Applying filter in a nested array of objects using for each

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter out the data points in an array of objects based on whether the particular property of the object is null. This array is however nested inside another array. See example below (i want to remove those objects from 'b' array which contain ***null*** in their 'c' property :

```js
var data = [{
  a: 1,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }]
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 13,
    d: 1
  }]
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }]
}]

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d['b'].filter(function(da) {
    return typeof(da['c']) == "number"
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

The above code is not removing the "null" value objects from the nested array and returns the whole array as it is. What am i doing wrong here?

**Update**: I understood my mistake and i have updated the post with an answer. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: The `.filter()` method returns a new array. Your code ignores the return value.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks a lot. Understood my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all the answers.I understood my mistake. I was not assigning the return value from .filter() to anything. Here's the updated code

```js
data1 = [{
  a: 1,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }]
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 13,
    d: 1
  }]
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }]
}]

data1.forEach(function(d) {
  d['b'] = d['b'].filter(function(da) {
    return typeof da['c'] === "number"
  })
})

console.log(data1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forEach((dataPoint) => {
  dataPoint.b = dataPoint.b.filter((dataChild) => {
    return typeof dataChild.c === 'number'
  })
})
```

You just have to reassign "b" to the new filtered array.

Comment: i'm getting an empty 'b' array in all cases

Comment: @VSharma fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You may try following code, using `reduce` function

```js
var data = [{
  a: 1,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 10,
    d: 20
  }]
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 30,
    d: 40
  }, {
    c: 13,
    d: 1
  }]
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: [{
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }, {
    c: 50,
    d: 60
  }, {
    c: null,
    d: 10
  }]
}];
var result = data.reduce((r,s) => {
  r.push(Object.assign({}, s, {b: s.b.filter(v => v.c)}));
return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the code errors out for me .... "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." ... sorry i'm not familiar with ...s notation ... is it something related to ES6?

Comment: Yes, it is, let change it to normal assigning.

Comment: I have removed the `...` dependency, please check

Answer (score 1):

```
data = data.map(value => ({...value, b: value.b.filter(innerValue => typeof innerValue.c === 'number')}))
```

Here's a [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pnxxgps8/)

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
data.map(item => ({ ...item, b: item.b.filter(itemB => itemB.c)}))
```

or

```
data.map(item => ({ a: item.a, b: item.b.filter(itemB => itemB.c)}))
```

which outputs:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 10,
        "d": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 10,
        "d": 10
      },
      {
        "c": 13,
        "d": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 6,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 10,
        "d": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```